# What does it mean watch expression missing

Tags: angularjs

Newbie quesiton, I read the document of [`rootscope.$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope). the syntax of `$watch`is

`$watch(watchExpression, [listener], [objectEquality], [deregisterNotifier]);`

But I see the examples use it like below.

```
var food;
scope.foodCounter = 0;
expect(scope.foodCounter).toEqual(0);
scope.$watch(
 // This is the listener function
 function() { return food; },
 // This is the change handler
 function(newValue, oldValue) {
   if ( newValue !== oldValue ) {
     // Only increment the counter if the value changed
     scope.foodCounter = scope.foodCounter + 1;
   }
 }
);
```

What does it mean missing `WatchExpression`? thanks.

Comment: Did you try $scope.$watch ? I think you are missinfg a $ sign at the scope

Comment: @BoasEnkler The code example is from the document I mentioned. you can see it there. thanks.

Comment: Simple explanation, watch expression is the scope variable name. example: $scope.foodCounter = {} . If you want to watch model, then watch expression is 'foodCounter' . So your problem is forget to define watch expression. you should write scope.$watch('foodCounter',....

Comment: No .The example is from official source . check the link I posted. thanks.

Comment: @Joe.wang: What does it mean _"What does it mean missing `WatchExpression`"_ ? Whre do you see that ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem As the example code put . `scope.$watch(
 // This is the listener function
 function() { return food; },...` the first argument is a listener function not the `WatchExpression` thanks.

Comment: You are right. I didn't aware of that function. I posted my answer.

Comment: :) Forgive me the mistake. the `watchExpression` can be a function . I already see it .`function(scope): called with current scope as a parameter.` thanks. @huntingung

Comment: I thought I have the excuse, the comment `// This is the listener function` should be on the `function(newValue, oldValue) `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

watchExpression can be both string or function - refer back to angularjs documentation as posted in the question. Given example as posted in the question will never trigger change handler because `food` is always undefined.

If you are using function as watchExpression, the function must return different value in order to trigger change handler. As documented in angularjs official document

> Expression that is evaluated on each $digest cycle. A change in the
>   return value triggers a call to the listener.

Code Snippet

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.food = "Laksa";
    $scope.foodCounter = 0;
    $scope.$watch(
    //this is watch expression using function
    function (scope) {
        return scope.food;
    },
    //this is listener - change handler
    function (newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log(newValue, oldValue);
        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
            // Only increment the counter if the value changed
            $scope.foodCounter = $scope.foodCounter + 1;
        }
    });
}
```

example - http://jsfiddle.net/4atA2/2/

this listener function is equivalent to `$scope.$watch('food',...` because it don't have additional logic. You have flexibility to add additional logic checking to decide whether want to trigger change handler or not. For example, watch on two scope variable.

example - http://jsfiddle.net/5NLNa/5/

```
function (scope) {
    if(scope.drink == "Milo") {
        return scope.food;
    }
},
```

Comment: I think the comments of example `// This is the listener function` display the wrong place . right ?

Comment: I think you are right. You might want to create a request to angularjs team to improve their document. I also confused when I first read it.

Comment: @Joe.wang, I changed the comments in the code to make it more clear.

Comment: I had report the issue to https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8254 , Please review it.

Comment: @Joe.wang, good job. I think this revision - https://github.com/pkozlowski-opensource/angular.js/commit/4e2e614ded485fbc9dcd1c474e9e1742863d9a92 make the thing clearer